# Authentication dependency injection with password users and Google users

Tags: python, authentication, fastapi

I am creating an app that allows users to either login with a username and password, or through Google authentication. I have signup and login working for both flows.  This is done by creating two separate login (and signup) endpoints for password and Google users.

I am now working on using dependency injection to allow users to request various endpoints which will decode their JWT and return the data if they are authenticated, as shown here: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/security/get-current-user/

This works fine for users that have logged in with a username and password, since this dependency uses `OAuth2PasswordBearer`.

However, this of course does not work with my Google users since

1. They don't have a password
2. The `tokenUrl` parameter for `OAuth2PasswordBearer` is set to my password users' login endpoint.

How can I achieve a `get_logged_in_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme))` function that words both for users who have logged in with a password and those who have logged in through Google?

Comment: Since you haven't included any code it's hard to say, but you can configure `OAuth2PasswordBearer` with `optional=True` as its argument; in that case it will return None instead of aborting the request. You can then add any secondary authentication (such as validating a token from Google instead) method as necessary. In many cases you could still have the same token for verification in your application, but create it based on two different sources (flow with Google, flow with local login)

Comment: @KOB: Have you figured out a solution for this?